# FileChannel - append byte buffer at eof?

Tags: java, bytebuffer, filechannel

I wondered if there is a possibility to add
a byte buffer to the end of a file by using the file channel's position method.

I have read that it is neccessary to open the file output stream
with the append flag

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ...;
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("path/to/file", true);
FileChannel channel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();

channel.write(bytebuffer);
channel.force(true);
channel.close();
```

but shouldn't it be possible to append the buffer
by modifiing the position of the channel.

["The size of the file increases when bytes are written beyond its current size"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ...;
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("path/to/file");
FileChannel channel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();

channel.position(channel.size()).write(bytebuffer);
channel.force(true);
```

I would be grateful for some explanations since the file
gets overwritten.

Comment: Show the code that proves it's not working as specified.

Comment: Is it a typo that the appending flag is not set for *FileOutputStream* in your second code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file gets overwritten in the second example because you didn't specify an `append` parameter with value `true`. After that, positioning it at EOF just positions it at zero.

Comment: so the file outputstream specifies if the content get's
overwritten or appended like
 > or >>

Comment: @EJP: It does matter where your position in Channel is, but while opening the Stream in not-appending mode it clears the file content (you should see it in your file browser) and the *channel.size()* will return 0. If you would call *position(1024)* you should get some unspecified first 1024 bytes and then whatever you write afterwards.

Comment: so if I would truncate a file I would need the flagg too

Comment: @jam *Either* you want to *append* to the file *or* you want to *truncate* it. Not both at the same time. If you want to truncate it you can either omit the parameter or set it to false.

Comment: @Alexander Agreed, I was referring to the OP's use of `position().`